# Image Rotating in Some Browsers...?

Tags: ipad, browser, photo

Does any one know what might be going on here? This is the [original link.](http://www.glamourunderground.com/1371/healthy-holistic-food-choices/)

[image: iPad][image: Chrome]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's related to whether or not you're holding the tablet in landscape/portrait-mode? That should've probably re-oriented the text too, but... yeah, that's just a guess.

Comment: What browsers are you comparing between? Safari on iPad versus a "regular" browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with iPad and found this discussion.

It turned out to be a different handling of JPEG with EXIF information saved.
Most browsers do not use it, iPad Safari does.

I'm working with PHP and solution was adding that in image resizing function:

```
$image->setImageOrientation(Imagick::ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
```